# Return pointer from function C

Tags: c, pointers, function

In my C program this function is going to handle all the work of opening a specific file and then return the file pointer, so main or other functions can read the content by using fp, but so far i haven't been able to get this to work.

I'm just learning the language, so it is possible that i am doing something very wrong.

```
int open_text_file(char text_file_name[])
{
    FILE *fp;

    if((fp = fopen(text_file_name, "r")) != 0)
    {
            return fp;
    }

    else
    {
            printf("Cannot open file \"%s\"\n", text_file_name);
    }
}
```

Comment: You're trying to return a pointer to a `FILE` structure as an `int`.  What (besides that error) are you seeing?

Comment: As a coding style issue, you should be comparing `fp` against `NULL` instead of `0`. If might also be clearer to separate the assignment and the comparison of `fp` into separate statements.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the first line, you have

```
int open_text_file(char text_file_name[])
```

This declares the return type as an `int`
What you should have is

```
FILE * open_text_file(char text_file_name[])
```

As well, in your "else" case, you should return something to indicate
an error to the caller.

```
return NULL
```

is an appropriate choice.  Make sure you check your return value when you call it, though.

Comment: Perfect, now i'm able to pass argv[1] to the function and print the content from main. 

As many of you say, i should compare fp to NULL, why that?

Comment: On some uncommon platforms, NULL may not be 0.  This isn't true in C++ however, or most places in practice.

Answer (score 6):

The function is a bit pointless, as all it does is what fopen() does, plus the error message. This is not good design, as the error branch must also return a (presumably NULL) pointer, which then must be tested again in the calling code. Better would be simply to say:

```
FILE * fp = fopen( somefile, "r" );
if ( fp == NULL ) {
   fprintf( stderr, "Cannot open %s\n", somefile );
   exit(1);   // or whatever you need to do to handle the error
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`FILE* open_text_file();` needs to be the prototype.

An `int` is not a `FILE*`.